# Make emails publicly available and searchable for non-technical people

Tags: email, archiving

I'm involved in an organisation where I'm currently conducting a radical transparency drive.
My intention is to make communications within the group public and searchable, starting by somehow mirroring email.
I do not want to hassle the members by putting a cc on everything, I'd like to to be "pull" not "push" :)

It's not a company, meaning we don't have a shared ad or anything.
There are no security requirements, no need to keep out non-members.
Are there any ways to accomplish this?

Comment: Note that we don't recommend "ways" here but software. So what should that software run on? What other criteria must be met? Full text search? Web access? Or rather synchronisation? If it comes to paid products, what is your budget for this? Also see: [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like [Mattermost](https://www.mattermost.org/), a self-hosted alternative to Slack. It enables you to consdoliate all team communication into one place, and hence making it searchable and accessible.

There is an addition to this called [Mattermail](https://github.com/rodcorsi/mattermail), which can listen to an email box and publish emails to channels/users in Mattermost. So the emails could be sent to a specific address and configured to broadcast on a Mattermost channel which all your users can see.

Other integrations can be found [here](https://about.mattermost.com/community-applications/).